# Dead lock in dispatch_sync

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Dead lock in following code. Why?

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue(); 
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Hello?");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Its in the documentation for `dispatch_sync` "Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock".

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  Do you understand what you are doing?  This example is the poster child for deadlocks in most literature I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `dispatch_sync` blocks the main thread thread until the block has finished running.

So it waits forever because the thread where the block is supposed to run (main thread) is blocked.

that code can be simplified down to

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Hello?");
});
```

Taken from the last paragraph of [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW28)

> Do not call the dispatch_sync function from a task that is executing on the same queue that you pass to your function call. Doing so will deadlock the queue. If you need to dispatch to the current queue, do so asynchronously using the dispatch_async function."

**TL;DR**

That code attempts to run a code-block on a thread which is blocked.